# Proving that the series $\sum [\log(2n+1)-\log(2n)]$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f(n)=\log(2n+1)-\log(2n)$. Using the Cauchy's condensation test we have: $$2^nf(2^n)=2^n[\log(2\cdot2^n+1)-\log(2\cdot2^n)] = \frac{1}{2}\log\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{2^{(n+1)}}\right)^{2^{n+1}}\right]\longrightarrow \frac{1}{2}\log(e)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Because $2^nf(2^n)$ does not converges to $0$ we conclude that $\sum 2^nf(2^n)$ is not convergent. By the test, $\sum f(n)$ is not convergent.

MY QUESTION: Is there an easier way to do this? Maybe some manipulation to avoid the Cauchy's test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: By mean value theorem, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $\xi_n\in(2n,2n+1)$ such that
$$\log(2n+1)-\log(2n)=\frac{1}{\xi_n}\geq\frac{1}{2n+1}\geq\frac{1}{3n}$$

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is. As it is a series with positive terms, you can use *equivalents*:
$$\log(2n+1)-\log(2n)=\log\Bigl(1+\frac1{2n}\Bigr)\sim_\infty\frac1{2n},$$
which diverges.

Comment: As an exercise, using the same technique to figure out the behavior of the series with general term $\frac{1}{\ln(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{\ln({2n})} $ may be interesting to the OP.

Comment: @ClementC.: If they know about Bertrand's series…

Comment: Granted... but that's a useful thing to know anyway.

Comment: I fully agree with you.